# setting hidden status in Mac with Python

Tags: python, macos, hidden-files

To toggle the hidden status of a file on Mac OSX in python, I use the following code:

```
st = os.stat(file_path)
os.chflags(file_path, st.st_flags ^ stat.UF_HIDDEN)
```

This works perfectly for "files" but does not work for "folders".
Note that I am not talking about files or folders that start with "."

---

EDIT:
The above code works for both files and folder, I made a mistake in my assumption...

Comment: It works fine for me; how are you defining `file_path`?

Comment: Ooops. The folder I was testing it with, was originally unhidden while I was assuming it is hidden....

Comment: You are right, it works